# Get Text Area field value with reference to code using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I have below code sample i want to find out the text area field value ,

```
<span dir="none"><span dir="ltr">
<textarea name="ctl00$m$g_547673d5_a6d6_4c03_aa47_d9ad28312f65$ff161$ctl00$ctl00$TextField"
    rows="6" cols="20" id="ctl00_m_g_547673d5_a6d6_4c03_aa47_d9ad28312f65_ff161_ctl00_ctl00_TextField"
    title="Description" class="ms-long" dir="none"></textarea>
<input name="ctl00$m$g_547673d5_a6d6_4c03_aa47_d9ad28312f65$ff161$ctl00$ctl00$TextField_spSave"
    type="HIDDEN" id="ctl00_m_g_547673d5_a6d6_4c03_aa47_d9ad28312f65_ff161_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_spSave">
```

I tried 
   var test = $('textarea[Title="Description"]').val();
   and
   var test=$(#ID).val();

so please help me.
Thanks,
Digambar K

Comment: using Jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using asp.net and jquery, as it look likes you are using asp.net

use

```
var textareaValue=$('#<%=textareaelementId.ClientId%>').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
     var thought = $('textarea[name=ctl00$m$g_547673d5_a6d6_4c03_aa47_d9ad28312f65$ff161$ctl00$ctl00$TextField]').val();
```

OR

```
     var thought = $('#ctl00_m_g_547673d5_a6d6_4c03_aa47_d9ad28312f65_ff161_ctl00_ctl00_TextField').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $("#ctl00_m_g_547673d5_a6d6_4c03_aa47_d9ad28312f65_ff161_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").change(function(){ 
      alert($("#ctl00_m_g_547673d5_a6d6_4c03_aa47_d9ad28312f65_ff161_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").val());

    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ydgvD/)

Comment: I want to capture value on form presave.

Comment: On Presave use if($("#ctl00_m_g_547673d5_a6d6_4c03_aa47_d9ad28312f65_ff161_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").val()=="") {alert("Please enter value.");return false;}